# Performing asynchronous operation within bluebird promise

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, bluebird, hapi.js

So, I've been beating this one about for a few days and I'm stumped as to what is the best way to solve it.  I am using Waterline/dogwater with HAPI and trying to do something broadly like so:-

```
wardrobe.find({WardrobeId: 5}).then(function(clothes) {
    //got my clothes in my wardrobe.
    clothes.find({Type: 'trousers'},{Kind: 'nice ones'}).then(function(trousers) {
        //got my nice trousers
        _.each(trousers, function(trouser) {
            //logic to see if these are my pink trousers
            console.log('color?', trouser.color);
        });
        console.log('ding');
    });
});
```

The trouble I have is the code will always `ding` before it outputs the trouser colors. This is because, as much as I understand it, `_.each` will make the code go async.  I tried to introduce Promises (bluebird), but without luck. I even looked at generators (Co), but my node version is fixed at pre v0.11.

I'd like to perform some database look-ups within the `_.each`, return these results (if any) to the trouser object, which can then be returned:-

```
wardrobe.find({WardrobeId: 5}).then(function(clothes) {
    //got my clothes in my wardrobe.
    clothes.find({Type: 'trousers'},{Kind: 'nice ones'}).then(function(trousers) {
        //got my nice trousers
        _.each(trousers, function(trouser) {
            //logic to see if these are my pink trousers
            db.colors.find({Color: trouser.color}).then(function(color) {
                //color here?
            });
        });
        console.log('ding');
    });
});
```

What is the best way to do this as efficiently as possible?

Help is appreciated.  Happy to return here and focus the question where needed.

Comment: You can use asynchrounus js code like blocking code by using ecmascript 6 features. Take a look at Task.js (http://taskjs.org/), but i am not sure if your js environment supports those es6 apis.

Comment: Assuming underscore/lodash - _.each is not async.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum But the db.colors.find seems to return a promise, which makes the whole thing async. If `yield` is available you can use Task.js to yield on that promise as long as it runs.

Comment: @NickRussler looks good, but do I need v0.11.*+? Currently, stuck on v0.10.33 on production.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum ```_.each``` is async and ^ as above, the code will always ding before the each completes regardless of size of array given to each.  Assuming that was the question?

Comment: I just tried with v0.10.33 and the `yield` keyword is not available, sorry.

Comment: Each is _not_ async. it's a synchronous method. OP is just doing async stuff in it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thank you for correcting my ```_.each``` misinformation ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well `_.each`  has nothing to do with asynchronicity. It's just a underscore/lodash way to do `trousers.forEach(...)`.

Your issue is with the `db.colors.find` method which performs an async operation. You can chain the methods if you want them to execute sequentially as such:

```
wardrobe.find({WardrobeId: 5}).then(function(clothes) {
    //got my clothes in my wardrobe.
    clothes.find({Type: 'trousers'},{Kind: 'nice ones'}).then(function(trousers) {
        //got my nice trousers
        var p = Promise.resolve();
        _.each(trousers, function(trouser) {
            //logic to see if these are my pink trousers
            p = p.then(function() {
                return db.colors.find({Color: trouser.color})
                    .then(function(color) {
                        // color here, they'll execute one by one
                    });
            });
        });
        p.then(function(){ 
            console.log('ding, this is the last one');
        });
    });
});
```

Or, if you want them to all happen in concurrently and not to wait for the previous one:

```
wardrobe.find({WardrobeId: 5}).then(function(clothes) {
    //got my clothes in my wardrobe.
    clothes.find({Type: 'trousers'},{Kind: 'nice ones'}).then(function(trousers) {
        //got my nice trousers
        Promise.map(trousers, function(trouser) {
            return db.colors.find({Color: trouser.color});
        }).map(function(color){
            console.log("color", color);
        }).then(function(){ 
            console.log('ding, this is the last one');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Spot on Benjamin. Thank you. +1